# Dockerized Node on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Error 502 BadGateway

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Node app (Isomorphic React app) dockerized and deployed to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I have all the information below but if you want a tldr: How do you configure port forwarding between a host and a container in AWS Elastic Beanstalk i.e. 5000:3000?

I want my application to work like this (the numbers are ports):

```
End User --80--> EC2 Instance / Nginx --5000--> Container --3000--> Application
```

I used the Dockerfile to EXPOSE 5000. I know that it's just a suggestion but as far as I know Amazon uses it to expose ports in the docker container instead of a docker-compose.yml. The app runs on port 3000. Code in the node to run on port 3000:

```
process.env.PORT || 3000
```

When trying to access the site using port 80, I'm getting a 502 Bad Gateway error.

I SSHed into the EC2 instance hosting my docker container. The nginx config for elasticbeanstalk looks like this:

```
upstream docker {
    server [CONTAINER_IP]:5000;
    keepalive 256;
}
```

The IP is the correct IP of the container (I checked by using Docker Inspect). When I run: `sudo docker ps -a`

I get:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
    REDACTED        REDACTED        "node server.js"    34 hours ago        Up 34 hours         5000/tcp            jolly_williams
```

If I run netstat on the EC2 host instance I see that port 80 is open:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80
```

When I look at the logs on the EC2 host instance I see this error multiple times for different resources:

request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://[CONTAINER_IP]:5000/", host: [Beanstalk URL] connection refused

**Now here is the kicker, it works when I run:**

```
sudo curl [ContainerIP]:3000 (from the EC2 host intance)
```

-or-

```
sudo docker exec -ti [CONTAINER_NAME] curl http://localhost:3000
```

Anyone know why the node is running off 3000 and not 5000? What can I do?

Comment: shouldn't you need a Dockerrun.aws.json file?

[Multicontainer Docker Configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_v2config.html)

specifically the following section:
`"portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "containerPort": 80
        }`

Comment: Thanks for the response! That's what I was thinking but I submitted a ticket to Amazon and they mentioned I wouldn't need a Dockerrun.aws.json file for a single docker configuration. I uploaded a Dockerrun.aws.json file where the containerport was 3000 and the host port was 5000 and I still got the 502. In my docker compose locally the ports are: 5000:3000

Comment: I think you should set your host port to 80, container port to 5000... because node is running on 3000... that I think is the right mapping.  
  
Does your ec2 instance accept traffic from port 80 from public... i imagine it would, but sometimes I would run into that issue if I did something funky with the configuration... if 3000 works i would set everything to 3000 and see if you can hit things and work backwards from there.

Comment: @MrCunninghamz I added this and still getting the 502 error:  {
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Ports": [
    {
      "HostPort": "80",
      "ContainerPort": "5000"
    }
  ]
  }

Answer (score 0):

Talked to AWS Support. They're saying that the docker port has to be the same port the application is listening on i.e. no port mapping